# Display Configuration Orientation name in Android

Tags: android

I want to display orientation name on screen. I am using following code:

```
Configuration config = mcontex.getResources().getConfiguration();
Log.d("Configuration","Orientation" + config.orientation);
```

Output: 1

But i want to display Orientation_Potrait or Orientation_Landscape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int orient = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
switch(orient)
        {

        case  Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE:

            Log.d("Configuration" ,"ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE");
        break;
        case Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT:
            Log.d("Configuration" ,"ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT");
            break;

            default:
            Log.d("Configuration", "default val");
            break;
        }
```

Try above code...

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
final int orientation = mContext.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
if (ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT == orientation) {
    // do something
} else if (ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE == orientation) {
    // do something else
}
```

Note that `SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT` and `SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE` are not the only possible option:

```
android: screenOrientation = ["unspecified" | "behind" |
    "landscape" | "portrait" |
    "reverseLandscape" | "reversePortrait" |
    "sensorLandscape" | "sensorPortrait" |
    "userLandscape" | "userPortrait" |
    "sensor" | "fullSensor" | "nosensor" |
    "user" | "fullUser" | "locked"]
```

The constants and its integer values are available in the `ActivityInfo` class.